# Binary Convolution

Tags: code-golf, binary, integer, bitwise

A binary convolution is described by a number `M`, and is applied to a number `N`. For each bit in the binary representation of `M`, if the bit is set (`1`), the corresponding bit in the output is given by XORing the two bits adjacent to the corresponding bit in `N` (wrapping around when necessary). If the bit is not set (`0`), then the corresponding bit in the output is given by the corresponding bit in `N`.

A worked example (with 8-bit values):

1. Let `N = 150`, `M = 59`. Their binary respresentations are (respectively) `10010110` and `00111011`.
2. Based on `M`'s binary representation, bits 0, 1, 3, 4, and 5 are convolved.

   1. The result for bit 0 is given by XORing bits 1 and 7 (since we wrap around), yielding `1`.
   2. The result for bit 1 is given by XORing bits 0 and 2, yielding `0`.
   3. The result for bit 2 is given by the original bit 2, yielding `1`.
   4. The result for bit 3 is given by XORing bits 2 and 4, yielding `0`.
   5. The result for bit 4 is given by XORing bits 3 and 5, yielding `0`.
   6. The result for bit 5 is given by XORing bits 4 and 6, yielding `1`.
   7. The results for bits 6 and 7 are given by the original bits 6 and 7, yielding `0` and `1`.
3. The output is thus `10100110` (`166`).

### The Challenge

Given `N` and `M`, output the result of performing the binary convolution described by `M` upon `N`. Input and output may be in any convenient, consistent, and unambiguous format. `N` and `M` will always be in the (inclusive) range `[0, 255]` (8-bit unsigned integers), and their binary representations should be padded to 8 bits for performing the binary convolution.

### Test Cases

```
150 59 -> 166
242 209 -> 178
1 17 -> 0
189 139 -> 181
215 104 -> 215
79 214 -> 25
190 207 -> 50
61 139 -> 180
140 110 -> 206
252 115 -> 143
83 76 -> 31
244 25 -> 245
24 124 -> 60
180 41 -> 181
105 239 -> 102
215 125 -> 198
49 183 -> 178
183 158 -> 181
158 55 -> 186
215 117 -> 198
255 12 -> 243
```

Comment: I think the title is wrong. it should be "Binary Revolution" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
(n,m)=>n^m&(n^(n*=257)>>1^n>>7)
```

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 35 bytes

```python
lambda m,n:n^m&(n^n*257/2^n*2^n>>7)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `n=255`?

Comment: @Neil Good catch. I don't see a nice way around that with mod, shifting instead for an extra byte.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 34 bytes

```
2#.[:({"_1],._1&|.~:1&|.)/(8#2)#:]
```

Straight-forward approach that applies the process defined in the challenge. Takes input as an array `[n, m]`.

Forms seven smileys, `[:`, `:(`, `:1`, `(8`, `8#`, `#:`, and `:]`.

### Usage

```
   f =: 2#.[:({"_1],._1&|.~:1&|.)/(8#2)#:]
   f 150 59
171
   f 59 150
166
   f 209 242
178
   f 17 1
0
   f 139 189
181
```

Comment: Something must be wrong if J scores the same as Python :D

Answer (score 2):

## x64 machine code, 17 bytes

```
88CD88C8D0C9D0C530E930C120D130C8C3
```

Disassembled:

```
0:  88 cd                   mov    ch,cl
2:  88 c8                   mov    al,cl
4:  d0 c9                   ror    cl,1
6:  d0 c5                   rol    ch,1
8:  30 e9                   xor    cl,ch
a:  30 c1                   xor    cl,al
c:  20 d1                   and    cl,dl
e:  30 c8                   xor    al,cl
10: c3                      ret
```

Suitable for the Win64 calling convention (arguments in rcx, rdx).

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 66 bytes

```
import Data.Bits
n%m=n.&.(255-m)+(rotate n 1`xor`rotate n(-1)).&.m
```

Works as intended when called with `Word8` data. Replace `(255-m)` with `complement m` (+5 bytes) to make the function work with any unsigned integral datatype.